# Picture "stuck" in a position

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I am inserting several figures in my text with the `\includegraphics` command but some of them are not being placed correctly and they don't move when I change the command's parameters.

This works correctly:

```
\begin{figure}[h]\caption{\label{f5}Innovation intensity}
\includegraphics[width=10.9cm,height=6cm]{c:/RESULTADO15.eps}
\end{figure}
```

But this does not work:

```
\begin{figure}[h]\caption{\label{f9}Chi-Square for trigger factors group}
\includegraphics[width=10.9cm,height=6cm]{c:/clustertrigger.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

and

```
\begin{figure}[h]\caption{\label{f9}Chi-Square for trigger factors group}
\includegraphics[bb=100 130 300 200,viewport=0 150 1000 380,scale=.6]{c:/clustertrigger.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

and also:

```
\begin{figure}[h]\caption{\label{dkpt} IT Employment in Denmark and Portugal}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[bb=-90 130 300 200,viewport=0 0 1000 380,scale=.4]{c:/dkpt.eps}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

So, I have the problem both with EPS and PDF files.
I tried changing `bb`, `viewport`, `scale`, `width` and `height` many many times with different values and the pictures are always in the same place. They don't move!! But some files are OK! I don't understand what's going on.

Can someone help me? I don't know what to try next because it seams as if the commands are not working proprely.

I am using MiKTeX.

Comment: It is very hard to offer any advice without a full document that shows the problem. You are using `[h]` which greatly rrestricts the places latex may place the float so increases the chance taht they go to the end of the document. rehoving `[h]` would be a good start. Otherwise add `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` so your document does not use real images just black rectangles and post a small complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: If you are using latex and dvips you need `.eps` If you are using pdflatex you need `.pdf` you can not by default use both in the same document. Just omit the extensions and then each engine will find teh files it can handle

Comment: [h] = "here" = "same place".  (david carlisle already said this, but it bears repeating.)  you're *telling* tex not to move them, and tex is doing what you're telling it to.

Comment: Fantastic answer from Frank Mittelbach on the behaviour of floats in LaTeX. Highly recommended that you read this! [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

Comment: I wasn't able to add the package[demo] as @DavidCarlisle suggested.

Comment: Also tried adding \clearpage before and after the \includegraphics bloc of commands. Nothing changes. The same with \begin{center}\end{center}: the image is ALWAYS placed on the lower right part of the page.

Comment: @MariaSilva How can you _not_ be able to  add `[demo]` to get`\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` ? Also please don't add code to comments, edit your question and add a complete document there. You can not add \clearpage inside \begin{figure} if that is what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I already have the`\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` working. This one was easy: I forgot to remove the `\usepackage{graphicx}`. Sorry for the mistake! 
I have \clearpage before and after the `\begin{figure} and the `\end{figure}`, respectively, not inside.
But something surprising happened with the Demo: The black boxes appear on the right positions! 
Any idea of why it does not work with the regular graphicx package?

Comment: It seams it is not a problem with TeX but with the picture files. But, what can that problem be? How can I solve it? I have other pictures that have no problem at all.